# Including platform-specific libraries with one header file and separate source files

Tags: c++, static-linking

I'm writing a platform-independent sockets library. The basic file structure is like this:

```
source directory
|_________________________
|            |            |
v            v            v    
header.hpp   win32        linux
             |            |
             v            v
             source.cpp   source.cpp
```

The header file contains any `#include`s that are universal across operating systems. The source files `#include` platform specific libraries.

I've built many projects like this, but I'm running into an issue with sockets. Because I'm specifying default values for my function parameters, `header.h` needs the platform specific libraries for `#defines` used in the header file,like `SOCK_STREAM`, `AF_INET`, and `SOMAXCONN`.

Now, I don't want to use `#ifdef _WIN32` statements in my header file, as I would like ALL platform specific code to be in the source files in separate folders.

Am I basically stuck between a rock and a hard place? Are avoiding `#ifdef #includes` and specifying default parameter values with header-dependent `#defines` mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get your default parameters by retrieving them via functions that are declared in your platform independent header and appropriately defined in your platform specific .cpp files.

Or, you could also declare them as extern consts in your platform independent header and appropriately define them in your platform specific .cpp.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some other default value that would normally be invalid. Your platform specific code could then detect this special default value and replace the value with the value that you actually want it to represent.

```
/* header */
int mysocket (int domain = -1, int type = -1, int protocol = 0);

/* implementation */
int mysocket (int domain, int type, int protocol) {
    if (domain == -1) domain = AF_INET;
    if (type == -1) type = SOCK_STREAM;
    // ...wrapper specific stuff for the platform...
    return ::socket(d, t, p);
}
```

Another possibility is just leave the parameters missing in your prototypes.

```
/* header */
int mysocket ();
int mysocket (int domain);
int mysocket (int domain, int type);
int mysocket (int domain, int type, int protocol);

/* implementation */
int mysocket () { return mysocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); }
int mysocket (int d) { retrun mysocket(d, SOCK_STREAM, 0); }
int mysocket (int d, int t) { return mysocket(d, t, 0); }
int mysocket (int d, int t, int p) {
    // ...wrapper specific stuff for the platform...
    return ::socket(d, t, p);
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of the first one, but I'm providing Doxygen documentation for other users, and having an invalid value as the default parameter probably wouldn't help with readability.

The second one is a good idea. I'll give that a shot now. I'd like to reduce code duplication, though.

Comment: @Littlegator: I tried to keep the amount of code duplication to a minimum. But, your documentation should just document a single API with default parameters. I am sure you thought of the idea of naming different constant (eg, mySOCK_STREAM), and using those for parameters had already crossed your mind, but then for consistency you'd have to replicate almost the entire set of constants in the socket library. If that is your intention anyway, Anon's idea is not a bad approach.

Answer (score 1):

Add a layer of abstraction in your library that is translated to the platform native type.

```
namespace MySocketLibrary
{
    enum SocketType
    {
        StreamSocket,
        DataGramSocket,
        RawSocket,
        // etc.
    }
}
```

For my platform specific `Win32` implementation then:

```
int translate_socket_type(const MySocketLibrary::SocketType socket)
{
    switch(socket)
    {
        case  MySocketLibrary::StreamSocket:
            return 1;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Lots of libraries (like `boost::asio`) do this.